# Do I no longer get reputation points for edits after going over 2000 reputation?

Tags: support

I've noticed that since going over 2000 reputation, I no longer get the 2 reputation points I used to get for doing edits on posts. Is this normal? And if so, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The points encourage you to do your duty to edit where you can, by way of instilling the SE desired habits into you.  Once you hit 2k, you shouldn;t be editing just for the measly points on offer, it should just be a habit.  The points help you get into that habit.  Think of it as getting promoted, you suddenly have to do unpaid overtime ;)

Comment: haha, alright. Just wondering what the policy was. Thanks.